# Custom Field for CiviCRM Membership not accessible from Drupal Rules module

Tags: civimember, drupal-7, rules

I'm trying to access a custom field used for **Membership** in CiviCRM from the **Drupal** **Rules** module.
But it seems this custom field, ***civicrm-membership:custom-8***, in not accessible from the Drupal Rules modules and it doesn't contain any value.

This is the rule I'm trying to create to **add a CiviCRM Contact to a Group**:

{ "rules_add_group_to_contacts" : {
"LABEL" : "Add Contacts to Groups",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"WEIGHT" : "1",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "devel", "rules_conditional", "civicrm_entity", "rules", "civicrm" ],
"ON" : { "**civicrm_membership_create**" : [] },
"DO" : [
{ "devel_debug" : { "value" : [ "***civicrm-membership:custom-8***" ] } },
{ "CONDITIONAL" : [
{
"IF" : { "text_matches" : {
"text" : [ "***civicrm-membership:custom-8***" ],
"match" : "Stay and Play - Coffee mornings"
}
},
"DO" : [
{ "civicrm_entity_rules_action_assign_contact_to_group" : {
"contact" : [ "civicrm-membership:contact-id-contact" ],
"group_id" : { "value" : { "18" : "18" } }
}
}
]

I'm working with **Drupal 7**.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can try here:

- Go to CiviCRM's **Administer menu >> System Settings >> CMS Database Integration**.  Compare the array there against the one listed in `settings.php`.  This array (in `settings.php`) must be updated when you add new custom field groups to CiviCRM (since they add new tables).  This is most likely your issue.
- Consider installing the `civicrm_entity` module, which should make your CiviCRM entities available as Drupal entities.
- Consider using CiviRules, which is a CiviCRM-native rules engine.  It's very similar to Rules, but it generally understands CiviCRM better.